# Capturing React Errors Globally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, exception, react-redux

I'm new to React. I want to capture all react uncaught and unexpected errors/warnings and i would like to log the errors to an external api.  I know its possible by Try Catch method but I'm planning to have it globally so that other developer need not to write the code each and every time.

I tried `window.onerror/addEventListener('error', function(e){}` which only captures the Javascript errors but not react errors.

This is similar to following post [How do I handle exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268791/how-do-i-handle-exceptions). But the solution given didn't meet my needs.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

Doc refs: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html

Real case of implementation example:

```js
// app.js
const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('app');

const render = (messages) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LanguageProvider messages={messages}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <ErrorBoundary>
            <App />
          </ErrorBoundary>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </LanguageProvider>
    </Provider>,
    MOUNT_NODE
  );
};

// ErrorBoundary component
export default class ErrorBoundary {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    // Display fallback UI
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return (
        <div>
          // error message
        </div>
      );
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

Comment: example with hooks?

Comment: Sorry but ErrorBoundary does not catch all exceptions 
https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#introducing-error-boundaries

Answer (score 2):

A thing to note is that errors in `async` methods like `async componentDidMount` won't be caught in a `error boundary`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event

Since not all errors will be caught we decided to use vanilla JavaScript `window.onerror` and `window.onunhandledrejection` in our project.

Complete question and answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64319415/3850405

Answer (score -1):

This will help: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html

Basically, with React 16 and above you can use `componentDidCatch()` lifecycle method in your parent most component to log all the uncaught exceptions.